# Ошибка при поиске процесса по названию

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, unicode

Пытаюсь получить process id следующим образом:

```
DWORD FindProcessId(string processName)
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 processInfo;
    processInfo.dwSize = sizeof(processInfo);

    HANDLE processSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);
    if (processSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return 0;

    Process32First(processSnapshot, &processInfo);
    if (!processName.compare(processInfo.szExeFile))
    {
        CloseHandle(processSnapshot);
        return processInfo.th32ProcessID;
    }

    while (Process32Next(processSnapshot, &processInfo))
    {
        if (!processName.compare(processInfo.szExeFile))
        {
            CloseHandle(processSnapshot);
            return processInfo.th32ProcessID;
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(processSnapshot);
    return 0;
}
```

Но ругается на `string process name`:

```
невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "WCHAR [260]" в "const _Elem *const " with [ _Elem=char ]
```

Как его объявить правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Несоответствие используемых строк C и C++.

Или компилируйте БЕЗ поддержки Unicode, просто ANSI (тогда C-строки будут `char*`, а не `wchar_t*`), или используйте соответствующие строки C++ - не `string`, а `wstring`.

Comment: Если использовать `wstring`, как мне передать правильно передать имя процесса? `DWORD processID = FindProcessId("222.exe");`

Comment: наверное L"222.exe"

Comment: @PavelGridin дал верный ответ.